# How can I fix this crack in my porch foundation?

Tags: masonry

We have an outdoor porch that is sitting on a slab (i believe). The one side of it has a pretty substantial crack and I'm wondering the best way to fix. Should i just get some masonry caulk and a backer rod, or should i get some mixture? I believe that they are just concrete bricks that are settling apart and/or water water hydraulicing. At it's largest the crack is about an 1/2 inch in height. The depth seems almost infinite at some points but is at least 2 inches. Here are some pictures for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: 16 inch ruler]

Advice, pertinent articles, or best googling terms greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may not have gotten much response here because the solution depends on the cause. If your foundation moves every year, most fixes will fail. You'd have to resolve the actual issue first.